# Changing border thickness of window does not show until resize?

Tags: c, winapi

I have the following code to change the style of my window at runtime:

```
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,  WS_EX_APPWINDOW|WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE);
```

The only problem is, it does not have the desired effect until I start dragging the window's edge to resize it.

Is there something I need to do to get this working?

I tried UpdateWindow and ShowWindow.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use SetWindowPos with the SWP_FRAMECHANGED flag for the update to take affect.  If you don't need the size or position changed OR SWP_NOMOVE and SWP_NOSIZE to SWP_FRAMECHANGED